# Grab Instagram access token from backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, instagram

I'm developing a mobile application by backbone. I need to authenticate user in Instagram. Instagram return the access token redirecting me with a url and in this url there is my access token.

For example I have go to this url:

```
window.location.replace("https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?  client_id=e40f15a****8a66&redirect_uri=http://example.com&response_type=token");
```

and Instagram redirect me to example.com appending my access token:

```
www.mysite.com#accesstoken=125424
```

How can I manage and grab my access token in backbone?

Can router intercept this url?

This is my router function that call url to authenticate user:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
        "": "prova",

        "aut":"provaaut",

    },



   provaaut: function(){





  window.location.replace('https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=e40f15a905**66&redirect_uri=http://example.coml&response_type=token');

AFTER WINDOW.LOCATION.REPLACE instagram redirect me to e new url containing token
   HERE I NEED TO GET REDIRECTED URL

   },
```

Is there a way in javascript to go to an url wait the redirect and get new url?

Comment: Did you try specifying as a route?  `routes: { 'accesstoken=:token': 'instagramAuthReturned' }`

Comment: Yes I did but doesn't works. The problem is route should get this url:www.mysite.com#accesstoken=125424. But it doesn't keep it and my page change because is a redirect@colllin

Comment: Please post more code showing what solutions you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with One Drive auth API. I solved it with using regex in the route.

Is it possible for you to set the redirect url as this? www.mysite.com/#accesstoken=125424

And the following code should work:

```
       routes : {

            "*default"                  : "index"
        },

       initialize : function() {

            $_ = this;

            $_ .route(/^accesstoken/, "token_redirect");
        },

       token_redirect : function(){
               //do your stuff
        }
```